# Excel VBA paramArray doesn't much like -A1:A10

Tags: excel, vba

I need a more flexible front-end to XIRR that can combine any number of cashflows and dates ranges and so I start out with

```
Public Function vbIRR(ParamArray args())...
```

and all that follows works just fine, such that when I call like

```
=vbIRR(A1:A10,B1:B10)
```

I get a good answer.  Trouble is that my A1:A10 may be laid out with the opposite sign than required to perform a valid XIRR calculation.  I could now adjust my VBA, of course, but I should more generally be able to simply write

```
=vbIRR(-A1:A10,B1:B10)
```

It does not work.  Debugging the VBA, I can see that args(0) is "error 2015".  (I also note that the standard XIRR similarly errors out.)

This is odd because when I look at "fx" (click the function wizard) to verify the inputs to the function, I cannot tell the difference between one and the other (beyond the desired change of signs to the values of the first range).  Both invocations show a range going in as the first argument.

Any pointers appreciated.  Thanks for reading.

EDIT:  The issue seems to relate to Control-Shift-Enter (CSE).  I noticed on many occasions in the past that "fx" seems much more indifferent to CSE v E.  XIRR will return a result if entered with CSE.  Curiously (and irritatingly), the TypeName of args(0) becomes "Variant()" (instead of "Range") in this invocation.  So I would need an additional type case.

Comment: you mean an array formulas,   using CSE tells excel the formula is to be seen as an arary,   then this allows excel to change the sign on the entire range

Comment: I, also, have a myXIRR function that allows non-contiguous ranges.  The arguments are typed as variant, and I include checking for `TypeOf X is Range` is done to convert the 2D array to a 1D array before processingit through through `XIRR`.  And, with CSE, it handles negated ranges just like the worksheet function would.

Comment: Interesting, Ron, that we both find the need to do the same thing.  There is something fundamentally deficient about the XIRR function.  I just posted my MMULT solution in answer to Leviathan.  However, I notice something quirky:  My ultimate answer results from the simple vbIRR=WorksheetFunction.XIRR(Cashflows,Dates).  This worked unconditionally in the test sheet I developed it in.  In the production sheet, it refused to work.  In the end I managed to get it to work by defining Cashflows() and Dates() "as Double".  Any idea what that might be all about?

Comment: @Ollie2893 I don't have that issue.  All of my VBA variables that are used are Variants, except for guess which is explicitly declared as Double.  Without seeing your code and/or data, it is hard to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could always add another parameter (before the ParamArray) to the function indicating if the values should be negated. In the VBA function you have full control over the data and can change it according to that parameter.

The parameter could be a `Boolean` indicating if the values should be negated, or it could be a `Long` or `Double` representing a multiplier (that would be -1 in your case).

Comment: Note that all arguments which precede `ParamArray` are required.  So you would have to enter this argument for every call to the function, not just for the one's that are negative.

Comment: Yes, I considered that solution and hated the implication that Ron gives.  However, I found an easier solution:  If instead of -A1:A10 I write MMULT(A1:A10,-1) I find it all works out.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass -A1:A10 as a parameter you are asking Excel to multiply a range by -1 and return an array as the parameter rather than a range.

So you are requesting array arithmetic and therefore need CSE entry.

The result is an array and therefore its a variant rather than a range: your VBA needs to handle both cases: I usually do a `If TypeOF arg is Range then arg=arg.value2` to convert the range to a variant.

under the covers the function wizard is using Evaluate on the arguments so it handles both cases transparently